# SQL Nested Aggregate Query- How do I get the number of customers per employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

The following is the prompt I need to answer:

List the number of customers for each employee. Include employee's name and number of 
customers labeled appropriately, listing the employee with the most customers first.

The following is my EMPLOYEES table:

```
create table EMPLOYEES
    (EmpID    char(4)         unique Not null,
     Ename    varchar(10),
     Job      varchar(9),
     MGR      char(4),
     Hiredate date,
     Salary   decimal(7,2),
     Comm     decimal(7,2),
     DeptNo   char(2)         not null,
         Primary key(EmpID),
         Foreign key(DeptNo) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DeptNo));


insert into EMPLOYEES values (7839,'King','President',null,'17-Nov-11',5000,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7698,'Blake','Manager',7839,'01-May-11',2850,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7782,'Clark','Manager',7839,'02-Jun-11',2450,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7566,'Jones','Manager',7839,'02-Apr-11',2975,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7654,'Martin','Salesman',7698,'28-Feb-12',1250,1400,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7499,'Allen','Salesman',7698,'20-Feb-11',1600,300,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7844,'Turner','Salesman',7698,'08-Sep-11',1500,0,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7900,'James','Clerk',7698,'22-Feb-12',950,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7521,'Ward','Salesman',7698,'22-Feb-12',1250,500,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7902,'Ford','Analyst',7566,'03-Dec-11',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7369,'Smith','Clerk',7902,'17-Dec-10',800,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7788,'Scott','Analyst',7566,'09-Dec-12',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7876,'Adams','Clerk',7788,'12-Jan-10',1100,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7934,'Miller','Clerk',7782,'23-Jan-12',1300,null,10);
```

The following is my CUSTOMERS table:

```
create table CUSTOMERS
    (CustID      char(6)       unique Not null,
     Name        varchar(45),
     Address     varchar(40),
     City        varchar(30),
     State       varchar(2),
     Zip         varchar(9),
     AreaCode    char(3),
     Phone       varchar (9),
     RepID       char(4)       not null,
     CreditLimit decimal(9,2),
     Primary key(CustID),
         Foreign key(RepID) References EMPLOYEES(EmpID));


insert into CUSTOMERS values (100,'Jocksports','345 Viewridge','Belmont','CA','96711',415,'598-6609',7844,5000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (101,'TKB Sport Shop','490 Boli Rd.','Redwood City','CA','94061',415,'368-1223',7521,10000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (102,'Vollyrite','9722 Hamilton','Burlingame','CA','95133',415,'644-3341',7654,7000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (103,'Just Tennis','Hillview Mall','Burlingame','CA','97544',415,'677-9312',7521,3000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (104,'Every Mountain','574 Surry Rd.','Cupertino','CA','93301',408,'996-2323',7499,10000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (105,'K + T Sports','3476 El Paseo','Santa Clara','CA','91003',408,'376-9966',7844,5000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (106,'Shape Up','908 Sequoia','Palo Alto','CA','94301',415,'364-9777',7521,6000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (107,'Womens Sports','Valco Village','Sunnyvale','CA','93301',408,'967-4398',7499,10000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (108,'North Woods Fitness Supply Center','98 Lone Pine Way','Hibbing','MN','55649',612,'566-9123',7844,8000);
```

The following is my query:

```
select ename, empId
from EMPLOYEES
where EmpID in
(select count(repid) as NumberOfCustomers
from CUSTOMERS
group by RepID);
```

Why is my query not working?

I know I want to match the empid from EMPLOYEES to the repID in CUSTOMERS and then COUNT how many times the rep ID shows up in CUSTOMERS.  The only reason I need the EMPLOYEES table is to out put Ename.  Im confused about the syntaxt I need to use because I need to output the count of RepID in the CUSTOMERS table

Comment: +1 for posting the scripts. All do like Jeff Oris does!

Comment: @Quassnoi: Except for posting apparent homework :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Common Table Expression` if you are using `SQL Server 2005` and above.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT RepID, COUNT(*) AS CNT
   FROM CUSTOMERS 
   GROUP BY REPID  
)

SELECT E.Ename, E.EmpID, ISNULL(C.CNT, 0) 
FROM EMPLOYEES E
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE C ON C.RepID = E.EmpID
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0aa4d/13)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employees e
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    customers c
        WHERE   c.repId = e.empId
        ) cc (cnt)
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
```

See this on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0a1a/1)

The same with a subquery:

```
SELECT  *,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    customers c
        WHERE   c.repId = e.empId
        ) cnt
FROM    employees e
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
```

Comment: Im not allowed to use CROSS APPLY

Comment: @JeffOrris: not allowed by whom, may I ask? Is it a homework?

Comment: yes.  Im having a hard time with this because my DB class was canceled and Im learning this on my own.  My DB book doesn't have good examples.

Comment: Should I do a nested query with an EXISTS somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query only has a `count(repid)`, which is a count, not the actual EmployeeID that your outer query requires in `where EmpID in (xxx)`.  Not sure why're you want a count in your inner query, because you'll lose it in the final result, but this should work:

```
 select ename, empId
 from EMPLOYEES
 where EmpID in (
    select repID
    from CUSTOMERS);
```

Comment: I get the following error message: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Try the updated version.  You don't need to do a group by, counting customers by repID, when you won't show it in the final query.  You could also do it an inner join, but I figured you wanted the inner query for a reason.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Do you think I should use an EXISTS somewhere?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  Or the wrong output data?   That would be really helpful to try and diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? or did i misunderstand

```
 SELECT ename, count(*) as NumCustomers 
FROM Customers INNER JOIN 
 Employees ON customers.repid = employees.empid GROUP BY repid,ename 
 ORDER BY numCustomers DESC
```

Comment: I can't use an INNER JOIN, must be a nested query to maximize efficiency

Comment: Since you need the employee's name, isn't it always going to be more efficient to join it back to the employees table? Since you need to retain the count from the customers table and also the employee's name that corresponds to that, I'm drawing a blank on how to do that without joining them.

Comment: I was told in class that rather than a join, a nested query always uses less resources

Comment: @JeffOrris "I was told in class", shouldn't that be "We were told in class" ? Who's the one telling you that nested query uses less resources, is he/she your classmate or your teacher?

Comment: @Michael Buen The professor told us.  However, after viewing the prompt, it is impossible to do a nested query for this.  After speaking with her, It is a join.  I was confused because it was a nested query assignment.  Sorry for any inconvenience.